# No correct data in fetching in react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Following is the code which is working fine on initial load time, but on clicking fetch data button its now fetching the data correctly. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Code -

```
const Sample = () => {
  const [todoCount, setTodoCount] = useState(3);
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Array(todoCount)
      .fill()
      .map((_x, i) => {
        return axios
          .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${i + 1}`)
          .then((res) => {
            const todo = res.data.title;
            setTodos((prevTodos) => {
              return [...prevTodos, todo];
            });
          });
      });
  }, [todoCount]);

  const fetchMore = (e) => {
    setTodoCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="example">
      <h3>Fetch data in a loop</h3>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((x, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{x}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <button onClick={fetchMore}>Fetch More</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sample;
```

CodeSandBox - https://codesandbox.io/s/black-mountain-y8xpl

Expected Result -

1. Initial Load - 3 Titles
2. Click "Fetch More" button it is adding 4 to the list, making it 7 instead it should be 4(increment by 1 only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the `setTodos` inside the map function, it runs every single time accumulating the `Todos`. You can try this out:

```
const Sample = () => {
  const [todoCount, setTodoCount] = useState(3);
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const todoArray = Array(todoCount)
      .fill()
      .map((_x, i) => {
        return axios
          .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${i + 1}`)
          .then((res) => {
            const todo = res.data.title;
            return todo;
          });
      });
    Promise.all(todoArray).then((todos) => {
      console.log(todos);
      setTodos(todos);
    });
  }, [todoCount]);
```

Setting the todos at once will also make the app re-render only once every fetchMore click, instead for every todo in the outcome.

Comment: that also solves your problem and you obtain your expected result, dont you?

Answer (score 1):

you face this behavior because once `todoCount` updates `useEffect` runs again. Now `todoCount` is 4 in total, this way it will fetch 4 more todos (which most will be repeated since only last `i` value should bring a new value).

given your code you could break into a initial count fetch on Mount, and other to fetch the subsequent ones:

```
const initialCount = 3
const baseUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos'

const Sample = () => {
  const [todoCount, setTodoCount] = useState(initialCount);
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Array(initialCount)
      .fill()
      .map((_x, i) => {
        return axios
          .get(`${baseUrl}/${i + 1}`)
          .then((res) => {
            const todo = res.data.title;
            setTodos((prevTodos) => {
              return [...prevTodos, todo];
            });
          });
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (todoCount === initialCount) return
    axios
      .get(`${baseUrl}/${todoCount}`)
      .then((res) => {
        const todo = res.data.title;
          setTodos((prevTodos) => {
            return [...prevTodos, todo];
          });
       })
  }, [todoCount])
```

though `todoCount` is derived from `todos` length which is a redundant state you can remove it. after that, you could change for only one `useEffect` and change fetch function to use `todos.length` as reference:

```
const initialCount = 3
const baseUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos'

const Sample = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Array(initialCount)
      .fill()
      .map((_x, i) => {
        return axios
          .get(`${baseUrl}/${i + 1}`)
          .then((res) => {
            const todo = res.data.title;
            setTodos((prevTodos) => {
              return [...prevTodos, todo];
            });
          });
      });
  }, []);

  const fetchMore = (e) => {
    axios
      .get(`${baseUrl}/${todos.length + 1}`)
      .then((res) => {
         const todo = res.data.title;
         setTodos((prevTodos) => {
           return [...prevTodos, todo];
         });
       });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but don't you think its creating duplicacy in code ?

Comment: Yes you are right, and I would abstract the axios logic to some function, and wrap into a useCallback. I didn't do it since it was not particularly the focus on the question.